# swap partion problem

Tags: partitioning, encryption, fstab, swap

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a DVD using 'Install alongside Windows 7.
The whole installation went smoothly with no problem. When I restarted I got a message while showing Ubuntu logo: `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 not found` (something like that).
I went so many Q&A here nothing worked. The common error I'm getting whatever I do is this:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
```

This is my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0f300f32-475d-4073-abc5-d9c3a2dc6f45 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=d7f4327f-7c60-494e-9425-6462faecdd96 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

`sda6` is my swap partition and it had a different UUID that GParted showed so, I updated with the current one, saved `fstab` and gave `sudo swapon --all` in terminal:

```
devanandh@Devanandh:~$ sudo swapon --all
[sudo] password for devanandh: 
swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
devanandh@Devanandh:~$ sudo swapon --all --verbose
swapon on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
```

Contents of `/etc/crypttab`:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=bd732933-344c-43cf-874b-3d58f6487c96 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

Output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="4A620A11620A0285" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Media Center" UUID="7204726B047231E9" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Black Hole" UUID="9682BC0C82BBEF3D" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="0f300f32-475d-4073-abc5-d9c3a2dc6f45" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="d7f4327f-7c60-494e-9425-6462faecdd96" TYPE="swap"
```

and this is my output.

Comment: The UUIDs of encrypted swap and the swap partition it is based on are supposed to be different. What does GParted show as the type of `sda6`? Can you post the contents of `/etc/crypttab`?

Comment: @seth - below thx so much for deleting - what I mean is, when one is able to delete the recovery partition, then one has a fancy machine - more fancy then before ! - if necessary - to get a fancy machine without recovery partition simply try to flash it during a thunderstorm - no joke ! it gets then the proper flash and runs then like an Apple ! - try it !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your encrypted swap is no longer encrypted. Encrypted swap typically shows up as *Unkown* in GParted, so if it didn't, something went wrong somewhere. Assuming you don't need encrypted swap and normal swap will do, you can do this:

1. Edit `/etc/fstab`, delete the line mentioning `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1`.
2. Uncomment the line just above it: remove the `#` at the start of the line, before `UUID=d7f4327f-7c60-494e-9425-6462faecdd96`. Save and exit.
3. Edit `/etc/crypttab`. Delete the contents. Save and exit.

Now, enable swap:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Test if it worked:

```
swapon -s
```

Comment: now i got this (gedit:26898): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
devanandh@Devanandh:~$ sudo swapon -a 
devanandh@Devanandh:~$ swapon -s
Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition 1979388 0 -1
devanandh@Devanandh:~$ gksu gedit /etc/crypttab
devanandh@Devanandh:~$

Comment: @daffyduck then it's working fine. Ignore the gedit errors. GUI applications often throw a bunch of warnings and errors that we don't normally see unless run from the command line.

Comment: yeah it did.swap is working fine.i had to restart and check again.its all good.Thank you very much for the help.it literally saved a lot of time.